# How do I clear the new line \n after reading a character?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

My main function is printing twice after I come from a function back to `main()`.

I'm pretty sure when it comes back to main it runs the cycle if I input `'\n'` and I'm not being able to fix this.

```
int main(){
char faz;

printf("What do you want to do?\nWrite C to create\nWrite R to read\nWrite U to edit\nWrite D to delete\nWrite E to exit the program\n>");
while((faz = getchar()) != EOF || faz != '\n')
{
  if(faz=='C') escreve();
  if(faz=='R') ler();
  if(faz=='U') editar();
  if(faz=='D') apagar();
  if(faz=='E') exit(1);
  else{ main();}
}
```

Any help would be welcome, this is a simple library management program.

Comment: Instead of calling `main` function recursively, try to use `do-while` looping statement.

Comment: 1) `int faz;` 2) `while((faz = getchar()) != EOF && faz != '\n')` 3) `else { return main();}`

Comment: Use `int faz;`  `char faz; ... while((faz = getchar()) != EOF || faz != '\n')` can be an infinite loop on platforms where `char` is like `unsigned char` and a problem for some characters when `char` is like `signed char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are recursively calling your main and that is what causes the problem, and you are calling `exit(1)` that normally signals an error for a normal behavior.  I suggest you do the following :

```
int main(){
 char faz;
 bool done=false;
 printf("What do you want to do?\nWrite C to create\nWrite R to read\nWrite U to edit\nWrite D to delete\nWrite E to exit the program\n>");
 while(((faz = getchar()) != EOF || faz != '\n') && (!done))
 {
    done=true;
    if(faz=='C') escreve();
    if(faz=='R') ler();
    if(faz=='U') editar();
    if(faz=='D') apagar();
    if(faz=='E');
    else{ 
        done=false;
        printf("Please enter a valid input\n");
    }

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: My teacher doesn't let us use return in the middle of a fucntion... Thanks anyways, I'm gonna keep trying

Comment: I modified the answer to suite your needs

Comment: Note that user input of `'E'` now returns 0 unlike OP's 1.

Comment: @chux I think he just want to quit the program when E is pressed and doing exit(1) is wrong because it crashes the program. The main returning any value other than 0 usually signals an error. In this case choosing E is a normal behavior so it should return 0